# iTunes app rejected - IAP

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, itunes

I implemented Unity IAP as in this sample project : https://forum.unity.com/threads/sample-iap-project.529555/ and it works, but the app is being rejected when I try to publish it on iTunes:

Your app offers a content subscription but does not have a mechanism in place to support the requirement that the subscription content be available to the user on all of their iOS devices.

To resolve this issue, please modify your app to include an optional user registration feature to deliver subscription content to all of the user's iOS devices. Such user registration must be made optional, not required. We also recommend indicating that registering is required to access the subscription content from their other iOS devices - and providing a way to register later, if users wish to have access to this content at a future time.

From what I understand, they want it so if an user buys something on iPhone, he also has it on iPad. The problem is, there is no documentation on how to do this(as this should be handled by Unity's IAP).
Thanks !

Comment: It sounds like you are using a non-renewing subscription. In this case you are responsible for providing some sort of server-based account that the user can use to login on other devices. You could switch to an auto renewing subscription in which case Apple will allow the user to restore their purchase on another device. In short, there is more to app development than just hacking on sample code.

Comment: Have you added a restore purchases function to your app? (including an in-game button)

Comment: @SteffanVenema yes, there is a restore button in the application, with the following code: https://hastebin.com/ataqopifal.cs

Comment: @Paulw11 aand you are right, my IAP's are non-renewable so they can't be restored by Apple's default service. Thanks a lot tho !

Comment: Then you will need to follow Apple’s advice. You will need some sort of database service where users can optionally register and then log in to their other devices in order to use their subscription. You could look at firebase

Comment: @SteffanVenema, I just tried to look at your restore button script. I keep getting a 522 error with this text: Contact your hosting provider letting them know your web server is not completing requests. An Error 522 means that the request was able to connect to your web server, but that the request didn't finish. The most likely cause is that something on your server is hogging resources. FYI